# Why won't my "WHERE" statements work in sql?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access database with 40 similar tables. Only a couple are listed below for simplicity. I want to grab 3 cells of data from a row if the date in that row is yesterday. The data comes from some other employee's homebrew spreadsheets that they refuse to give up. So I can't change the column names or get them all on the same workbook template. I've tried some variations on the code below but I can't get the dates to work right. If I drop the WHERE statement it returns everything. But I really need it whittled down. Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1081
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
UNION

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1145
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
UNION

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1149
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
UNION 

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1228
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
UNION 

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1353
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
;
```

Comment: try using parantheses (date()-1)

Comment: what happens if you hard code the date value? will it return data? thinking it may be an issue with the syntax of the date function

Comment: What syntax is `[Customer name]`?

Comment: Is [Quote Completed] a date or a datetime? You might use `WHERE cast([Quote Completed] as date) = date() -1` instead if the latter is true.

Comment: Hard coding the date value, produces the same return as the Date function, nothing. I've got to be missing something simple here.

Comment: "Formatting" is nothing to do with the database itself.  What may be important, however, is the *data types* of the `[Quote Completed]` columns.  Did you try @Joe's suggestion?

Comment: What worked? You wrote that under both the question comments and @sqrfv's answer.

Comment: It will be forever an internet mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a where condition on each section of your union? Or do you just want the whole results filtered?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
    FROM 1081
    UNION
    SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
    FROM 1145
    UNION
    SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
    FROM 1149
    UNION 
    SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
    FROM 1228
    UNION
    SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
    FROM 1353) U
WHERE [Quote Completed] = date()-1
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to use dateadd:

```
SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1081
WHERE [Quote Completed] = DateAdd('d',-1, date())
```

Added link: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php

Comment: It's still not showing me any results when I hit Run. This is only like my 4th database ever so I may be missing something stupid simple.

Comment: Access permits the ordinary addition and subtraction operators to be used to add or subtract numbers of days to/from `date` values.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1081
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1)
UNION

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1145
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1)
UNION

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1149
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1)
UNION 

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1228
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1)
UNION 

SELECT [Customer name],[$ Amount], [Quote Completed]
FROM 1353
WHERE ([Quote Completed] = date()-1)
;
```